# Android permission setting for platform apps

Tags: android, android-permissions

Inside adb shell I am able to set and read back:

```
setprop audio.foo.bar 1
getprop audio.foo.bar
```

inside my code:

```
SystemProperties.set("audio.foo.bar","1");
```

above code triggered permission error.

what I have done so far:

1. property_service.c tried to add oneof the following, without success.

   {"audio.foo.bar.", AID_MEDIA, 0 };

   {"audio.foo.bar", AID_SYSTEM, 0 };

   {"audio.foo.", AID_SYSTEM, 0 };

   {"audio.foo.", AID_MEDIA, 0 };

   {"audio.", AID_SYSTEM, 0 };

   {"audio.", AID_MEDIA, 0 };
2. inside AndroidManifest.xml tried to include one of the following:

   android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"

   android:sharedUserId="android.uid.media"

What else I miss out?

Comment: are you already add the service in your manifest?

Comment: not sure what you mean, how does it look like?  is it I need to add in more inside AndroidManifest.xml? I do have "android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"

Comment: what is *"property_service.c"* anyway? is that java class?

Comment: it is white list of property setting services.

Answer (score 0):

1. {"audio.", AID_SYSTEM, 0 }; added into property_service.c
2. android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system" added into AndroidManifest.xml
3. SystemProperties.set("audio.foo.bar","1");

Apparently, there is no android:sharedUserId="android.uid.media".
But I hope I can learn where to provide custom uid, if that even possible?

image need to be rebuild new image, somehow the setup I am using reload recovery image for every boot for every adb push I done. Actually done the right things from the start. T_T|||